# Find and replace image using openCV

Tags: c++, c, image, opencv

I am using openCV to write a code that can find and replace one image with another image

Here is my 1st image [image]

Now i have 2nd image as this [image]

I need to replace the second image with this [image]

and final output should be like this [image]

So how to start about ? I am not sure how can i find it, I tried using [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) but the images are supposed to be exactly equal for template matching, and when my images are distorted or skewed in some manner then it doesn't work ?

How can i match the image get the bounds using openCV, and replace with another image ?
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: What are you passing in for the template matching? If you want to paste the daisies onto the larger image then in the template matching you should be passing through the big image with a sample of the red flowers so it can tell you where in the picture they are. THEN you can paste the daises on top of them, knowing where they are.

Comment: Template matching doesnt work for skewed images, so i dont want to use it, i need a more robust solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [SURF Algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) for matching the images as show [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

The code

```
line( img_scene , scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object .cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object .cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
```

will draw image not on the scene image but on object so use this

```
line( img_scene , scene_corners[0], scene_corners[1] , Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
line( img_scene , scene_corners[1] , scene_corners[2] , Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
line( img_scene , scene_corners[2] , scene_corners[3], Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
line( img_scene , scene_corners[3] , scene_corners[0], Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
```

Now to replace the image use this

```
Mat temp;
cv::resize(mReplacementImage,temp,img_object .size());
warpPerspective(temp, mReplacementImage, H, img_scene .size());
Mat mask = cv::Mat::ones(img_object .size(), CV_8U);
Mat temp2;
warpPerspective(mask, temp2, H, img_scene .size());
mReplacementImage.copyTo(img_scene , temp2);
cv::imwrite("output.bmp",img_scene );
```

Answer (score 1):

SURF algorithm, that's you want it. [OPENCV SURF Example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)